# Avoid errors like "the process can't access the file because it's being used by another process" after download a file asynchronously in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, download, process.start

So, I have follow this tutorial: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/185093-download-file-asynchronously-with-progressbar/ and I have made all similar as the author said...

The problem is that when I want to open the downloaded file I cannont because an exception is thrown: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

```
 Private Sub Download(ByVal fileDownload As String, ByVal filePath As String)
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient 'I tried to Dispose it after the download but nothing happens, the exception was still there...
    AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client_DownloadCompleted
    client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(fileDownload), filePath)
End Sub

Private Sub Check()

    Dim fileCheck As String = "C:/File.exe" 'Executable that won't open
    Dim fileDownload As String = "http://sie.com/" 'Link of the download

    If Not File.Exists(fileCheck) Then
        Download(fileDownload, fileCheck)
    End If

    Process.Start(fileCheck) 'This throws an exception

End Sub

Private Sub client_DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    Check() 'Check again after the download causes an exception
End Sub
```

I have checked if exist a Dispose function for webclient, but it doesn't do anything... And I don't know anything else to do, so, what do you recommend me to do?

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this line :

```
Download(fileDownload, fileCheck)
```

you are passing filecheck(file that cause the error) i suppose that you have write wrong one which should be

```
Download(fileDownload, fileOpen)
```

coz file path should be the file of an executable as per description in process.Start

**REVIEW**

here a fully functional code which seems exactly your:

```
   Dim fsave As String = "C:\Users\Giorgio\Desktop\tp1.exe"
Sub Main()

    WebClientTest()

        Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Sub WebClientTest()

    Dim wb As New WebClient

    AddHandler wb.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf DownloadCompleted
    wb.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/files/audacity/2.0.5/audacity-win-2.0.5.exe/download"), fsave)


    Console.WriteLine("Run download")

End Sub

Private Sub DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("DownloadCompleted")
    Process.Start(fsave)
End Sub
```

it work perfectly and no issue about load audacity.exe when process.start

make that process changed event show if your file has issue in example if totaly bytes are = to -1 there's something wrong in file source.

Comment: Sorry, I have to update the code I didn't relised of that variable... This is a txt where I write some text... But It doesn't have any relation with the download or the executable... Please recheck code ;)

Comment: Okey, I fix it... The problem was that I called the function during the download and I didn't realised of this... Now I fix it... :P